# How to plot column bar using matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I have a sample data file contains following data

```
Item,%Frequency
 1,15.08
 2,11.80
 3,10.52
 4,9.00
 5,6.74
 6,4.94
 7,5.84
 8,6.34
 9,6.42
 10,5.24
 11,3.64
 12,2.10
 13,1.46
 14,0.50
 15,0.06
 16,0.06
```

I am trying to plot the column bar using matplotlib using following scripts.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
lines = []
with open("sample.txt") as fname:
    lines = fname.readlines()
    size = len(lines)

i = 1
x = []
y = []
while i<size:
    ip = lines[i].split(',')
    x.append(ip[0])
    y.append(ip[1])
    i+=1
plt.bar(x, y)
plt.savefig("output.png")
plt.close()
```

I am getting following error messages.

```
$ python plot_v1.py 



File "plot_v1.py", line 22, in <module>
    plt.bar(x, y)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2573, in bar
    ret = ax.bar(left, height, width=width, bottom=bottom, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 2046, in bar
    self.add_patch(r)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1550, in add_patch
    self._update_patch_limits(p)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1570, in _update_patch_limits
    xys = patch.get_patch_transform().transform(vertices)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/patches.py", line 626, in get_patch_transform
    self._update_patch_transform()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/patches.py", line 619, in _update_patch_transform
    bbox = transforms.Bbox.from_bounds(x, y, width, height)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 829, in from_bounds
    return Bbox.from_extents(x0, y0, x0 + width, y0 + height)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

When I try to print list x, it gives following results

```
[' 1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4', ' 5', ' 6', ' 7', ' 8', ' 9', ' 10', ' 11', ' 12', ' 13', ' 14', ' 15', ' 16']
```

How to resolve the error and plot the column graph ?

Comment: That's an interesting error. But I cannot reproduce it. Can you provide the full error traceback and state which version of matplotlib you are using? Concerning the underlying problem, you probably forgot to convert your strings to numbers.

Comment: I have added complete error traceback.

Comment: I cannot find a version of matplotlib where this would occur and you didn't tell yours. Anyways, as commented you need to convert your strings to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

From my limited experience it looks you're reading in all of your data as strings rather than numeric types. One easy fix I've used is to use the [astype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) function to change the data type. I also use numpy's [loadtext](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) function whenever I load data - you don't need to create a file object and can quickly specify the data type and delimiter you're looking for.